# How to run this sql in laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4

I am trying to run a vary complex sql in laravel:

```
 SELECT 
            SUM(t.total_revenue) as total_revenue, 
            SUM(t.cost1) as cost1, 
            SUM(t.cost2) as cost2, 
            SUM(t.vouchers_applied) as vouchers,
            t.month,
            t.year
        FROM (
              SELECT DISTINCT
                  cb.total_revenue, 
                  cb.cost1,
                  cb.cost2,
                  cb.vouchers_applied,
                  MONTH(cb.reference_date) as month,
                  YEAR(cb.reference_date) as year
                  FROM db1.voucher v 
                  INNER JOIN db1.voucher_use vu ON vu.voucher_id = v.id 
                  INNER JOIN db1.customer cu ON cu.account_number = vu.account_number 
                  INNER JOIN db2.customer_breakdown cb ON cb.id =  cu.id 
                  WHERE 
                    v.voucher_code LIKE '###%'
              ) t
        GROUP BY month, year
```

So Basically here I will have to join 4 tables together and then go a sum and groupby time. I tried to run this as a raw query using

```
DB::select(DB::raw("{{SQL goes here}}"));
```

but nothing is returned.
I also tried to convert everything to collection and do the fancy logic on my web server, but it seems fairly slow.

Any ideas that can help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

`DB::raw()` dont demand wrapping in select func.
to check out what query was executed just use `dd(DB::getQueryLog());`
Hope it helped a little bit